# Vmware: Disabling Alarms and Alerts at a cluster level

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have been struggling for a bit trying to figure out how to shut off Alarms and alerts from a Cluster level in vCenter 4.x. We have 10 clusters in one vCenter Datacenter and during maintenance periods I would like to shut off / disable the alarms and alerts per cluster level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alarms can only be disabled at the level for which they are defined. So, if the alarms are set at the vcenter level, it's all or nothing.

To do what (I think) you want, you would need to disable existing alarms at the higher level and then define them at each cluster level. Kind of a pain, but a PowerCLI script could ease that somewhat. Then, you can disable on a per-cluster basis.